# MySQL Group Replication fails to understand "::ffff:" IP Address

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, group-replication

I'm trying to set up group replication using 3 x MySQL 8.0.16 databases, but when I start up the second Node it fails. The error log reports:

```
[GCS] Connection attempt from IP address ::ffff:10.12.1.2 refused. Address is not in the IP whitelist.
```

But if I add a whitelist:

```
group_replication_ip_whitelist="::ffff:10.12.1.2";
```

I get:

```
[GCS] Invalid IP or subnet mask in the whitelist: "::ffff:10.12.1.2";
```

Is this an issue with the server at my end, or an issue with Group Replication not understanding the IP Address?

My configuration is:

```
server_id=<different for each one>
gtid_mode=ON
enforce_gtid_consistency=ON
binlog_checksum=NONE
transaction_write_set_extraction=XXHASH64
group_replication_group_name="8112d18e-9e6e-11e9-a526-0e51be33883f"
group_replication_start_on_boot=off
group_replication_local_address= "10.12.1.1:33061" /*This is different for each one*/
group_replication_group_seeds= "10.12.1.1:33061,10.12.1.2:33061,10.12.1.3:33061"
group_replication_bootstrap_group=off
```

If I look on the first nodes error log I can see:

```
Connection attempt from IP address ::ffff:10.12.1.2 refused. Address is not in the IP whitelist.'
```

But again, adding it to a whitelist throws the above error about there being an invalid IP Address,

Comment: How did you add the instance to the cluster? Here is a similar question that helped me with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55189823/11417822

Comment: Did you ever find a solution this??? Am also stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

That output is done in the most generic possible way, using IPv4-mapped IPv6 address.

It should work if you simply add:

```
group_replication_ip_whitelist="10.12.1.2";
```

Comment: Alas, it makes no difference I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but had the same issue with 8.0.28 on Ubuntu. Found that dual stack implementation was causing ipv6 to grab 33061. IPv4 was getting all other ports. Not the best solution, but disabling IPv6 will solve this.